# How to Str::shouldReceive? (mocking Illuminate\Support\Str)

Tags: unit-testing, laravel, facade, mockery

I have a class that uses `Str::random()` which I would like to test.

But when I use `Str::shouldReceive('random')` in my test, I get a BadMethodCallException saying the method shouldReceive does not exist.

I also tried to mock the class directly and bind it to the IOC but it keeps executing the original class, generating a random string and not the return value I set on the mock.

```
    $stringHelper = Mockery::mock('Illuminate\Support\Str');
    $this->app->instance('Illuminate\Support\Str', $stringHelper);
    //$this->app->instance('Str', $stringHelper);

    $stringHelper->shouldReceive('random')->once()->andReturn('some password');
    //Str::shouldReceive('random')->once()->andReturn('some password');
```

Answer (score 2):

What you tried will work as long as you also use IoC to resolve the binding of that class.

```php
$instance = resolve(\Illuminate\Support\Str::class);
$instance::random();
```

Answer (score 1):

you could not use laravel Mock because Str::random() is not Facade.
instead, you can create a new class with a method that set your test environment. like this:
‍‍‍

```html
<?php

namespace App;


use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class Token
{
    static $testToken =null;
    public static function generate(){
        return static::$testToken ?:Str::random(60);
    }

    public static function setTest($string){
        static::$testToken = $string;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Accroding to [Mockery docs](https://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/public_static_properties.html), if you want to mock public static method, you should use [alias](https://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/creating_test_doubles.html#creating-test-doubles-aliasing).

Therefore, you can:

```php
Mockery::mock('alias:Illuminate\Support\Str')->shouldReceive('random')->once()->andReturn('some password');
```

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to mock out the Illuminate\Support\Str in this way (see [mockery docs](https://docs.mockery.io/en/latest/reference/public_static_properties.html). This is how I would test it.

In the class which tries to generate a random string, you can create a method to generate a random string and then override that method in your test (code not actually tested):

```
    // class under test
    class Foo {
        public function __construct($otherClass) {
            $this->otherClass = $otherClass;
        }

        public function doSomethingWithRandomString() {
            $random = $this->getRandomString();
            $this->otherClass->useRandomString($random);
        }

        protected function getRandomString() {
            return \Illuminate\Support\Str::random();
        }
    }

    // test file
    class FooTest {
        protected function fakeFooWithOtherClass() {
            $fakeOtherClass = Mockery::mock('OtherClass');
            $fakeFoo = new FakeFoo($fakeOtherClass);
            return array($fakeFoo, $fakeOtherClass);
        }

        function test_doSomethingWithRandomString_callsGetRandomString() {
             list($foo) = $this->fakeFooWithOtherClass();
             $foo->doSomethingWithRandomString();
             
             $this->assertEquals(1, $foo->getRandomStringCallCount);
        }

        function test_doSomethingWithRandomString_callsUseRandomStringOnOtherClassWithResultOfGetRandomString() {
            list($foo, $otherClass) = $this->fakeFooWithOtherClass();

            $otherClass->shouldReceive('useRandomString')->once()->with('fake random');
            $foo->doSomethingWithRandomString();
        }
    }
    class FakeFoo extends Foo {
        public $getRandomStringCallCount = 0;
        protected function getRandomString() {
            $this->getRandomStringCallCount ++;
            return 'fake random';
        }
    }
```